# redirect clients of your android hotspot to custom web page or send them a link notification

Tags: notifications, wifi-hotspot, captive-portal

redirect clients of let's say my android hotspot to custom web page or send them a link notification without rooting if it is possible. The thing i want to accomplish is to be able to send a link the moment someone connects to my mobile wifi hotspot with no password and to get redirected to a url or get a notification.

The concept is to be able to send notification to multiple people cellphone to cellphones and only the sender is necessary to have the app. Can that be without rooting the phone?